# Connecting excel file to pgAdmin table using Python

Tags: python, sql, excel, postgresql, pgadmin

I have excel file which has 7 columns and daily informations. I'm trying to connect excel file to pgAdmin table. But not achieving to this, it's not working. Please, help me.
My database name is "exceltodatabase". Table name is "daily". It has 7 columns. Hostname is "localhost" . Port is: 5432. Password is: 1234

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:1234@localhost/exceltodatabase')
with pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/TelegramBot/ActivateBot/masters.xlsx') as xls:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls)
    df.to_sql(name='daily', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: I think you mean the PostgreSQL database, because pgAdmin doesn't have tables. What error message do you get? "it's not working" is not very useful information for debugging.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the xlsx file format as that isn't exactly dataframe friendly. I think you would be better using a CSV version. With that in mind could you not use COPY to load it from the csv if you have a local postgres already running. ?

Comment: Define 'not working'.